# Fit rectangles in a larger rectangle in JavaScript/React

Tags: reactjs, rectangles, packing

I am creating a function that is able to calculate how many small rectangles can be fit into a container one. The problem that I'm stuck with - not quite sure how to proceed with the calculations.

The smaller rectangle has always the same size, exactly the same as the container. The params that I'd have for this function are:
const smallerRect = {width: 100, height: 100}
const containerRect = {width: 1000, height: 1000}
const margin = { top, right, bottom, left} - eventually I'd like to add margin to my rectangles

How should I approach that?

Comment: Bit vague this one friend. Would be nice to see an attempt to understand what you're trying to do. Sounds like you need an array of smaller rectangles that you loop through. You would do it row by row, filling each of them.

Comment: hello, sorry if the explanation was confusing. That is the problem to actually make an attempt, not quite sure on how to start with it. But I agree, I'd need an array with small rects so the larger one gets filled out with them